# Using NSTask to launch a Ruby script (Shenzhen)

Tags: objective-c, ruby, xcode

I am trying to generate an IPA with the Shenzhen script: https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen

Here is the code I currently have:

```
-(void)startBuildIPAForProject:(NSString*)path
{
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
    [task setCurrentDirectoryPath:path];
    [task setArguments:@[@"ipa build",@"-c",@"Release"]];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                                   encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"task output: %@",string);

    [task waitUntilExit];
}
```

When executing [task launch] I get the following output from the console:

```
/bin/bash: ipa build: No such file or directory
```

When I use the regular terminal ipa build is working (that is, it tells me there exists no Xcode project in the current dir)

I'm a bit lost, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ipa` script will need to be in your application's `PATH` environment variable (or in the same directory as your binary.) An easy fix would be to specify the full, absolute path to `ipa` in your arguments. i.e. change:

```
[task setArguments:@[@"ipa build",@"-c",@"Release"]];
```

to

```
[task setArguments:@[@"/full/path/to/ipa build",@"-c",@"Release"]];
```

Comment: Alternatively, just call the ipa utility directly with setLaunchPath, if you're not using bash for anything else.

Comment: You might be able to bundle ipa in with your application too. Then you won't have to rely on users installing it.